# Should this method be static?

Tags: class, methods, instance

I am fairly new to java and am currently debugging a program. So I have a class that has a simple method with a few calculations. Basically when I call this method from another class to use a variable (that happens to be part of an array where some of it is being calculated) I get the calculation I need. Then I call it once more in another class, it calculates again and my numbers become compromised. Is there a way to have this method take in some value, calculate and then stay put?

This is the array class. I need to instantiate this once and then have the values for the arrays be static when I call it again. Is there a way to make the method stay put while I just call the arrays?

In another class I use PlanMat pm = new PlanMat()
then something like pm.materials(fSi, fS, fO); and to call an array pm.rho0[48];

```
public class PlanMat {
Constants con = new Constants();
double GPa = con.GPascals;
Main m = new Main();

public int i ;
public int eos [ ];    
public double rho0 [ ]; 
public double c [ ];
public double nn [ ];
public double Ks0 [ ];
public double Ksp [ ];

public void materials(double fSi, double fS, double fO)
{

i = 0;
eos = new int [ 51 ];
rho0 = new double [ 51 ];
c = new double [ 51 ];
nn = new double [ 51 ];
Ks0 = new double [ 51 ];
Ksp =new double [ 51 ];

        double fFeS = ( ((con.M_Fe / con.M_S) + 1) * fS );
        double fFeSi = ( ((con.M_Fe / con.M_Si) + 1) * fSi);
        double fFeO = ( ((0.950 * con.M_Fe) + con.M_O) / (1.95 * con.M_O) * fO);
        double fFe =  1.0 - fFeS - fFeSi - fFeO;


        i = 48;
        eos [ i ] = 1; 
        rho0 [ i ] = 1.0 / ( (fFe / rho0[3]) + (fFeSi / rho0[21])  
                    + (fFeO / rho0[22]) + (fFeS / rho0[13]) );

        Ks0 [ i ] = fFe * Ks0[3] + fFeSi * Ks0[21] + fFeO * Ks0[22]
                    + fFeS * Ks0[13]; 
        Ksp [ i ] = fFe * Ks0[3] + fFeSi * Ks0[21] + fFeO * Ks0[22]
                    + fFeS * Ks0[13]; 
        c [ i ] = 0.0;
        nn [ i ]= 0.0;
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

```
class a{

......
function()
{
a,b
}
}

class b{
...function(){
here u need your variable value.
call the function and store the variable value in new variable.
}
}
if u need to do same u can do
class c{
...function(){
here u need your variable value.
call the function and store the variable value in new variable.
}
}
```

Comment: If i have this variable equal to the calculation, wouldnt it be updated each time I call the method anyhow? like: int a = x + 1 ; int b = a;

Comment: one doubt ... do u need the same value of variable when u take it on next time also.....this is ur need

Comment: Yeah I just posted the class with the arrays. I need to call the class  which will take in user values and then calculate for a spot in the arrays (48). It spot on when I instantiate the class once but, when I do it again, it messes with the values.

Comment: When u take the value of variable from another class store that variable values into new variable in your class. when u need the value of variable once again dont call the function. instead of that take value from the bew variable

Comment: I have done that but, I am running into a problem where I need to call it once more in another class.

Comment: save the variable value in another variable in where u need the value of the variable.

Comment: wouldnt calling the function again make the class do the calculation again?

Answer (score 1):

There are two wasys to acheive this:

`First`:
   You should write `set` and `get` methods, call to `set` method to set the values and `get` method to `get` the values. You would be setting the values say in class1 you set the values and now if you want the same values in class2 to you would be calling your get method to get the values as an array and pass this array as an argument to the constructor of class2.

`Second`:
      You can pass the whole object to the class2 constructor and use that object in that class your values will be same and data will not be compromised but for this you will have to implement the Serializable on your data class(That you are using in both.)

Comment: Ah it looks like I am still ignorant of the methods you speak of. Ill take a look into those

Comment: Would you be able to toss me an example?

Comment: @handroski you may see this documentation on oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html
do you have knowledge of `Constructors` in OOPS?

Comment: @handroski you can read this too, in case if you do not know how to pass Class object as an argument http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html